# how to get results of my webservice with jsonp?

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I want to call one of my webservices via jsonp with angularjs.

When i call http://example.com/files?callback=JSON_CALLBACK directly in my browser, i got :

```
["folder1", "folder2"]
```

When i call from angularjs with :

```
$http.jsonp('http://example.com/files?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
     .success(function(data){ 
         console.log(data);
         $scope.folders = data;
});
```

console.log does not appear....
What am i doing wrong ?

Must my webservice return

```
JSON_CALLBACK(["folder1", "folder2"])
```

? Should i do it manually in my api ? browser don't do that automatically ?

Comment: Yes service must wrap response with the value from the GET parameter `callback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are currently returning (`["folder1", "folder2"]`) is not valid [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). The JSON result must be wrapped by a javascript function call in order to be valid JSONP.

For example, when you use the URL like this:

```
http://example.com/files?callback=JSON_CALLBACK
```

Angular will replace the `JSON_CALLBACK` parameter with an angular function name (created internally), like:

```
http://example.com/files?callback=angular.callbacks._0
```

Your server would then need to be able to read that `callback` parameter and return the result like this:

```
angular.callbacks._0(["folder1", "folder2"]);
```

This is not an automatic mechanism, you need to implement that logic on your web server.

Comment: ok, i understand, that was exactly my question. I try, and then mark resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Following code snippet.

```
(function($) {
var url = 'http://example.com/files?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
       console.dir(data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i'm getting error case with "undefined" as e.message

Comment: Yes, its calling error callback function because you returned invalid json string that's why code arises  the exception

Comment: Return data something like {"data":["folder1","folder2"]}

Answer (score 0):

bmleite was right, I had to implement this logic on my API.
In my example, my server is made with Silex :

```
public function index()
{
    $callback = $this->request->get('callback');
    $files    = $this->app['file.manager']->getList();

    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse();
    $response->setData($files);
    $response->setCallback($callback);

    return $response;
}
```

And it works perfectly now. Thank you.